# Sync Firestore with Realtime database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, components, iot

I have my flutter application connected with firestore.

But when it comes to the IOT component that works with my app i have to use the realtime database. How can i auto update the firestore data with the realtime database

Example

> Realtime
>
> Vehicle -> ABC123 -> latitude:3.256

> Firestore
>
> Vehicle -> ABC123 -> latitude:3.256

Auto sync of the databases within a specific period time

Comment: Per the `iot` tag **DO NOT USE**. Please clarify your question with appropriate tags as `IOT component` is very vague.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create a Cloud Function that watches for changes in the Realtime Database and writes those changes to Firestore.

Something like this (untested but should get you started):

```
exports.syncFirestore = functions.database.ref().onWrite((change, context) => {
  const db = admin.firestore();

  db.document(change.after.key).set(change.after.val());
});
```

Comment: As a firestore rule ?

Comment: Cloud Function as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more about cloud functions

Comment: @coder You can find information on how to use Cloud Functions [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing)

Comment: @RafaelLemos ok thank you i'll look into it. Is it a payed version since im developing this as an academic prototype

Comment: You'll need a billing account but Google gives you 2 million free invocations per month so you shouldn't be charged for it.